# Get ImageView Width and Height before setting the bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

I have an action bar, text view and an imageview in my layout. Imageview has widht and height match_parent. Imageview takes the rest of the space left in the view. I want to set a bitmap to the view but that is too huge. So I first want to get the width and height of the imageview and use them to scale down the bitmap and then set it the imageview. I have tried getting width and height of the imageview in OnCreate, but that is coming as 0,0 probably because imageview has not been created yet.

Please suggest how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: User ViewTreeObserver in your onCreate method.

Comment: I tried ViewTreeObserver on imageView in OnCreate but still the width and height of the imageView inside onGlobalLayout is 0,0. :-(

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `ViewTreeObserver` onPreDrawListener, this gets called after everything is measured and right before it is drawn

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewBYId(R.id.imageview);
ViewTreeObserver observer = iv.getViewTreeObserver()
observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

    public boolean onPreDraw(){
        observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try it but I am curious will it be a good practice to set bitmap to imageview in OnPreDraw ?

Comment: why do you think its not? its the only way to get the size of the imageview for scaling down an image if you need to

Comment: I am getting IllegalStateException on

on observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.checkIsAlive(ViewTreeObserver.java:720)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:563)

Comment: `if(observer.isAlive()` then remove the listener

Comment: I tried it. its not throwing any exception now. However, onPreDraw() gets called three times and imageview heght and width is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in layout changes of the particular ImageView, then a layout listener on it might be the way to go:

```
imageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this link?

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

There is basically such a method especially used for preventing memory problems because of large bitmaps. Your first read the dimensions and then laod the scaled sample.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am awere of this. I want to know the dimensions of the imageview and use those dimensions to scale down the bitmap. So the problem is not about loading the bitmap into memory, its about getting the dimensions of the imageview before setting bitmap.